# Fastest public-key algorithm for testing purposes

Tags: gnupg

As part of an automated test suite I need to run a lot of `gpg --encrypt` and `gpg --decrypt` processes.

In order to make each invocation of `gpg --encrypt` and `gpg --decrypt` faster, I would like to use a very fast public key algorithm.

I understand that the fastest ciphers are also those providing the weakest security, especially at small key sizes. Security, however, is not important issue in this case: the passphrase-less key is even released publicly as part of the test suite.

For reference, this is what my GnuPG version supports:

```
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA
Cipher: 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH, CAMELLIA128, 
        CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

To recap, what is the fastest combination of algorithm and key length available in GnuPG?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve with mass key generation? In a test suite, usually predictable execution is preferred. Why do you need to create new keys every time? Otherwise: Choose the smallest possible key size, as this requires less entropy. Waiting for random data will very likely be the determining time factor when creating lots of keys. You might want to have a look at the way [cryptico](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico) uses a passphrase as seed, requiring less entropy and writing your own code to create key pairs.

Comment: The key is generated only once but there are tons of `gpg --encrypt` operations. The slower an algo is the more these `gpg --encrypt` process take. I will reword my question to make this clear.

Comment: Null encryption and authentication will be fastest.

Comment: @Flexo: gpg2 does not accept `NULL` as `Key-Type`.

Comment: OpenPGP does not accept no public-private crypto algorithm. It actually accepts plain text as symmetric encryption, but I'm not sure whether the implementations accept it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's going to vary from machine to machine and GPG binary to GPG binary; does the machine offer AES-NI instructions, does your GPG binary use them, is it using 64-bit operations, are XOP or AVX instructions available and used by your binary, etc.

There is only one answer: benchmark it on your particular setup!

[Daniel Kahn Gillmor posted just such a benchmark script](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2010-September/039575.html) on the gnupg users list in 2010, including a SHA1 sum and a signature, naturally.

Note that output is from the Unix time command, formatted as + in seconds.

If you want something different, then modify the script!

```
#!/bin/sh

# Author: Daniel Kahn Gillmor <dkg@fifthhorseman.net>
# Date: Tue, 28 Sep 2010 14:25:19 -0400

# This script produces some roughly-formatted OpenPGP performance data
# against different algorithms and keysizes


set -e

REPEAT=100
ASYM_ALGOS="RSA DSA"
KEY_SIZES="1024 2048 3072 4096"
DIGESTS="SHA1 SHA224 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512"
CIPHERS="3DES AES AES192 AES256"

if gpg --debug-quick-random --version >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
    QUICKRANDOM=--debug-quick-random
elif gpg --quick-random --version >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
    QUICKRANDOM=--quick-random
else
    printf "don't know how to set quick random number generation"
    exit 2
fi

encalgo() {
    if [ "$1" = "DSA" ]; then
    printf "ELG-E"
    else
    printf "%s" "$1"
    fi
}

describe_system() {
    # FIXME: this is fairly Linux-specific.  it'd be better to use
    # something more generic to get info about the CPU and RAM
    # available:
    cat /proc/cpuinfo 2>&1 || :
    free 2>&1 || :
    uname -a
    gpg --version
}

# quick key creation:
setup() {
    rm -f testmsg
    for rep in $(seq 1 25) ; do
    echo "this is a test message for benchmarking OpenPGP signature validation times." >> testmsg
    done
    for algo in $ASYM_ALGOS; do
    for size in $KEY_SIZES; do
        if [ "$algo" = "DSA" ] && [ "$size" -gt 3072 ]; then
        # gpg can't do DSA > 3072 bits
        continue
        fi
        mkdir -m 0700 -p ${algo}-${size}
        if printf 'Key-Type: %s
Key-Length: %s
Key-Usage: sign
Subkey-Type: %s
Subkey-Length: %s
Subkey-Usage: encrypt
Name-Real: OpenPGP Benchmark Key %s %s bits
Name-Comment: DO NOT USE!
' "$algo" "$size" $(encalgo "$algo") "$size" "$algo" "$size" | GNUPGHOME=${algo}-${size} gpg $QUICKRANDOM --batch --gen-key ; then
        for digest in $DIGESTS; do
            output=${algo}-${size}/testmsg.${algo}-${size}-${digest}.asc
            if ! GNUPGHOME=${algo}-${size} gpg --digest-algo "$digest" --clearsign < testmsg > ${output} ; then
            rm -f ${output}
            fi
        done

        for cipher in $CIPHERS; do
            output=${algo}-${size}/testmsg.${algo}-${size}-${cipher}.asc
            if ! GNUPGHOME=${algo}-${size} gpg --armor --cipher-algo "$cipher" --encrypt -r 'Benchmark' < testmsg > ${output} ; then
            rm -f ${output}
            fi
        done
        else
        rm -rf ${algo}-${size}
        fi
    done
    done
}


signing() {
    for algo in $ASYM_ALGOS ; do
    printf '%s Signing (x%d)\n' $algo $REPEAT
    for length in 'digest:' $KEY_SIZES; do
        if [ -d "${algo}-${length}" ] || [ "$length" = 'digest:' ]; then
        printf '%s\t' "$length"
        for digest in $DIGESTS; do
            if [ "$length" = 'digest:' ]; then
            printf '%s\t' "$digest"
            else
            for x in ${algo}-${length}/*; do
                cat < "$x" > /dev/null
            done
            targfile=${algo}-${length}/testmsg.${algo}-${length}-${digest}.asc
            if [ -e $targfile ]; then
                stats=$(bash -c "time -p for seq in $(seq 1 $REPEAT | tr '\n' ' '); do
GNUPGHOME=${algo}-${length} gpg --digest-algo $digest --sign >/dev/null 2>/dev/null < ./testmsg
done" 2>&1)
                printf '%s+%s\t' $(printf "%s" "$stats" | grep ^user | cut -f2 -d' ') $(printf "%s" "$stats" | grep ^sys | cut -f2 -d' ')
            else
                printf 'X\t'
            fi
            fi
        done
        printf '\n'
        fi
    done
    done
}

verifying() { 
    for algo in $ASYM_ALGOS ; do
    printf '%s Verifying (x%d)\n' $algo $REPEAT
    for length in 'digest:' $KEY_SIZES; do
        if [ -d "${algo}-${length}" ] || [ "$length" = 'digest:' ]; then
        printf '%s\t' "$length"
        for digest in $DIGESTS; do
            if [ "$length" = 'digest:' ]; then
            printf '%s\t' "$digest"
            else
            for x in ${algo}-${length}/*; do
                cat < "$x" > /dev/null
            done
            targfile=${algo}-${length}/testmsg.${algo}-${length}-${digest}.asc
            if [ -e $targfile ]; then
                stats=$(bash -c "time -p for seq in $(seq 1 $REPEAT | tr '\n' ' '); do
GNUPGHOME=${algo}-${length} gpg --verify >/dev/null 2>/dev/null < $targfile
done" 2>&1)
                printf '%s+%s\t' $(printf "%s" "$stats" | grep ^user | cut -f2 -d' ') $(printf "%s" "$stats" | grep ^sys | cut -f2 -d' ')
            else
                printf 'X\t'
            fi
            fi
        done
        printf '\n'
        fi
    done
    done
}


encrypting() {
    for algo in $ASYM_ALGOS ; do
    printf '%s Encrypting (x%s)\n' $(encalgo "$algo") $REPEAT
    for length in 'cipher:' $KEY_SIZES; do
        if [ -d "${algo}-${length}" ] || [ "$length" = 'cipher:' ]; then
        printf '%s\t' "$length"
        for cipher in $CIPHERS; do
            if [ "$length" = 'cipher:' ]; then
            printf '%s\t' "$cipher"
            else
            for x in ${algo}-${length}/*; do
                cat < "$x" > /dev/null
            done
            targfile=${algo}-${length}/testmsg.${algo}-${length}-${cipher}.asc
            if [ -e $targfile ]; then
                stats=$(bash -c "time -p for seq in $(seq 1 $REPEAT | tr '\n' ' '); do
GNUPGHOME=${algo}-${length} gpg --cipher-algo $cipher --encrypt -r Benchmark >/dev/null 2>/dev/null < ./testmsg
done" 2>&1)
                printf '%s+%s\t' $(printf "%s" "$stats" | grep ^user | cut -f2 -d' ') $(printf "%s" "$stats" | grep ^sys | cut -f2 -d' ')
            else
                printf 'X\t'
            fi
            fi
        done
        printf '\n'
        fi
    done
    done
}


decrypting() {
    for algo in $ASYM_ALGOS ; do
    printf '%s Decrypting (x%s)\n' $(encalgo "$algo") $REPEAT
    for length in 'cipher:' $KEY_SIZES; do
        if [ -d "${algo}-${length}" ] || [ "$length" = 'cipher:' ]; then
        printf '%s\t' "$length"
        for cipher in $CIPHERS; do
            if [ "$length" = 'cipher:' ]; then
            printf '%s\t' "$cipher"
            else
            for x in ${algo}-${length}/*; do
                cat < "$x" > /dev/null
            done
            targfile=${algo}-${length}/testmsg.${algo}-${length}-${cipher}.asc
            if [ -e $targfile ]; then
                stats=$(bash -c "time -p for seq in $(seq 1 $REPEAT | tr '\n' ' '); do
GNUPGHOME=${algo}-${length} gpg --decrypt >/dev/null 2>/dev/null < $targfile
done" 2>&1)
                printf '%s+%s\t' $(printf "%s" "$stats" | grep ^user | cut -f2 -d' ') $(printf "%s" "$stats" | grep ^sys | cut -f2 -d' ')
            else
                printf 'X\t'
            fi
            fi
        done
        printf '\n'
        fi
    done
    done
}


run() {
    WORKDIR=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/openpgp-benchmark.XXXXXX")
    OUTPUT=$(mktemp "$(pwd)/openpgp-benchmark.$(date +%F_%T | tr ':' '-').XXXXXX")
    printf 'Working in %s...\n' "$WORKDIR"
    cd "$WORKDIR"
    ( describe_system
        setup
        signing
        verifying
        encrypting 
        decrypting ) | tee "$OUTPUT"
    printf 'log written to %s...\nPlease mail back to Daniel Kahn Gillmor <dkg@fifthhorseman.net>.\n' "$OUTPUT"
}

action="$1"
if [ "x$action" = "x" ]; then
    action=run
fi

case "$action" in
    setup|describe_system|signing|verifying|encrypting|run)
        "$action"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 [setup|describe_system|signing|verifying|encrypting|run]  " >&2
        exit 2
        ;;
esac
```